# get values inside a column of lists in tibble R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm noob in R and I'm trying to obtain the text inside a Tibble column of lists in R

This is the column of the Tibble (values are in string type)

data$revisions

[image: Tibble Column]

Example of the value inside revisions column

```
dput(data[1,'revisions'])

structure(list(revisions = "[{\"body\":\"<div>No me refiero 
especifico por La Segunda, voy al \\\"juicio de valor\\\" malicioso 
(tipo copuchenta) que emitió, contra un medio (cualquiera que haya 
sido), en un contexto parlamentario.</div>\"}]"), 
row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I just want to extract the data in "body" and use the  text values in a new column

Comment: Please provide example data that can be readily copied, pasted and worked on (e.g. as the output from entering your data into```dput()```).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JSON, but the linebreaks were causing fromJSON to fail, so I swap them out, read it in , and then swap back. seems to work.

```
mydf <- structure(list(revisions = "[{\"body\":\"<div>No me refiero 
especifico por La Segunda, voy al \\\"juicio de valor\\\" malicioso 
(tipo copuchenta) que emitió, contra un medio (cualquiera que haya 
sido), en un contexto parlamentario.</div>\"}]"), 
          row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

mydf2 <- mydf |>
  mutate(rev2 = fromJSON(str_replace_all(revisions,
                                         pattern = "\n",
                                         replacement = "_*_")) |> pull(body) |>
           str_replace_all(pattern = fixed("_*_"),
                           replacement = "\n"))  

cat(mydf2$rev2)
```